# Seek Bar Does not move with audio track running. Unable to debug

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

Followed a Youtube tutorial. But my seek bar does not move with the audio. I have added the handler and also a runnable to according to the tutorial. Am i misssing something

```
private MediaPlayer music;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
SeekBar seek;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gnr_sweet);
    seek = (SeekBar)  findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seek.setMax(music.getDuration());
    playCycle();
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean userinput) {
            if(userinput){
                music.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
public void playCycle(){
    seek.setProgress(music.getCurrentPosition());
    if(music.isPlaying()){
        runnable= new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playCycle();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

I am a little new to android dev so any sort of input can be useful.
Am i missing something at the playCycle() method ?
There is a clicklistener for play pause button as well, I had just removed it from the code snippet for clean code for stackoverflow

Comment: hey i am watching the same video and got stuck your question helped me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my part I create a Runnable.
Then I think you need to set the seekBar.setProgress first before calling handler.postDelayed. This works in my part.

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        displayCurrentTime();
        seekBar.setProgress((int) player.getCurrentTimeMillis());
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) length);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

 @Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            seekbar.setProgress(progress);
        }
        length = progress;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

and

```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

it worked for me

Comment: Kinda confusing, elaborate a little more please ?

Answer (score 0):

remove this condition

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean userinput) {
    // if(userinput){
        music.seekTo(progress);
    // }
}
```

progress bar change

```
public void playCycle(){
    int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
    seek.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
    if(music.isPlaying()){
        runnable= new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playCycle();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. After removing the condition, no change. The seek bar still remains static at the postition where it has been moved.

Comment: @VinayRathod I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle